# How to convert PCIe x1 cables to work with x16 sized cards?

Tags: motherboard, bridge, pci-express, bridging

I have some PCIe x1 extension cables.

I have some PCIe x16 video cards.

I have some PCIe x16 (and one PCIe x1) outlets on my motherboard.

What can I do to the PCIe x1 riser cables to make the motherboard read the X16 sized video card?

Simply plugging an x1 extension cable into an x16 card does not seem to work.

Comment: Use 16 of them. *runs*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I have some PCIe x16 video cards.
>
> I have some PCIe x16 (and one PCIe x1) outlets on my motherboard.
>
> What can I do to the PCIe x1 riser cables to make the motherboard read the X16 sized video card?

Put it to one side (and then put the x16 video card into the x16 motherboard slot?)

Maybe you could use a [PCIe x1 to PCIe x16 adapter](http://www.startech.com/product/PEX1TO16R-PCI-Express-X1-to-X16-Slot-Extension-Adapter-for-1U-Servers)